# Linker command failure with Honeywell Captuvo iOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, barcode-scanner, honeywell

I am integrating a Honeywell Scanner sled into an iOS app. I have downloaded the SDK from Honeywell and followed the installation guide.

There are two files: `Captuvo.h` and `libCaptuvoSDK.a`

I have added a bridging header and imported the Captuvo.h header file as follows:

```
#import "Captuvo.h"
```

I have added the `libCaptuvoSDK.a` file to my project and made sure it is properly referenced under 'Linked Frameworks and libraries:

[image]

The app builds properly but then any reference to the Captuvo SDK causes a linker command failure. So adding this line of code anywhere causes the error:

```
let device = Captuvo.sharedCaptuvoDevice()
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or is this potentially a bug in the SDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all delete your derived data.

Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations

Click the grey arrow next to derived data and remove the folder(s) with your project name.

Also do a clean, Cmd+shift+k

Try updating the pod as well

```
pod install --repo-update
```